# Local class variable location

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management

What happens if a class instantiates all it's local variables on the stack (ie: `int i; //An integer` on stack versus `int *p; //Pointer to an int`) while the class itself is instantiated on the heap?  Where are the class members?
Here's an example:

```
class A  {
  public:
  int a, b; //These are instantiated on the stack, if the line were written outside a class definition.
  A(int _a, int _b)  { 
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
  }
};
```

Now, if we instantiate A like this:

```
#include <iostream>
A* classA = new A(1,2);
int main(void)  {
  std::cout << classA.a << "\t" << classA.b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Where are `classA.a` and `classA.b`?  Are they on the program stack?  Are the automatically put on the heap instead, as `classA` is?

Not a problem in most cases, I wouldn't think, but it might be helpful to know...

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't local variables, they are class members.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Okay, I replaced local variables with class members.  What's the difference other than naming convention, by the way?  My C++ book says local variables and class members interchangeably...

Answer (score 4):

> `int a, b; //These are instantiated on the stack,`

No, these are not instantiated on the stack. Member variables are parts of the instance data structure, and thus are allocated in the same memory chunk as the class instance. Only if the class instance is on the stack, then the instance fields are there as well.

Answer (score 1):

This line is factually incorrect

```
  int a, b; //These are instantiated on the stack, normally
```

It depends on how the object is created - using `new` or on the stack

Comment: I think the error is in clarity.  I didn't convey what I meant properly. if `int a, b;` was written outside a class, then they would be instantiated on the program stack.  I'll clarify this in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a definition of a data structure; a block of memory. It does not define where that block of memory comes from. However, all the memory for a single object comes from the same place.

```
 static Class A ;
```

Allocates all the data for A in a stack program section.

```
. . . . . 
{
    Class A ;
}
```

Allocates ALL the data for A on the stack (or whatever mechanism used---the stack).

```
Class *A = new A ;
```

Allocates all the data for A in dynamic memory.